# Question about a certain involution on a Coxeter group $W$.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, coxeter-groups, weyl-group

This is a small question that arose while reading the paper *On Okuyama's Theorems About Alvis-Curtis Duality* by M. Cabanes. It can be read [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.nmj/1252934368).

Let $(W,S)$ be a finite Coxeter system, $l$ the length function, and for $I,J\subseteq S$, let $D_{I,J}$ denote the set of $w\in W$ such that $l(uwv)=l(u)+l(w)+l(v)$ for any $u\in W_I$, $v\in W_J$.

For $I\subseteq S$, let $w_I$ denote the longest element of $W_I$. Now fix $J\subseteq S$, and define $\theta\colon W\to W:w\mapsto w_Sww_J$. The paper states (in paragraph 3 of the proof of Proposition 3 on page 5) that $\theta(D_{I,J})=D_{I^{w_S},J}$, where $I^{w_S}=w_SIw_S$.

Is this statement true? If $u\in W_{I^{w_S}}$, and $w\in D_{I,J}$, then I calculate, since $w_Suw_S\in W_I$, 
$$
\begin{aligned}
l(u\theta(w)) &= l(uw_Sww_J)=l(w_Sw_Suw_Sww_J)=l(w_S)-l(w_Suw_Sww_J)\\
&= l(w_S)-[l(w_Suw_S)+l(w)+l(w_J)]\\
&= l(w_S)-[l(u)+l(ww_J)]\\
&= l(w_S)-l(u)-l(ww_J)\\
&= l(w_Sww_J)-l(u)=l(\theta(w))-l(u)
\end{aligned}
$$

when one should instead expect to get $l(u\theta(w))=l(u)+l(\theta(w))$. Am I making a silly error somewhere, or is the statement wrong?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but isn't the statement false already when $J=\emptyset$, in which case $w_J=1$ and the map is $\theta(w)=w_S w$, where $w_S$ is the longest element of $(W,S)$? For instance, $\theta(1)=w_S$, which is not a minimal length coset representative for any $I$ except $I=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Stephen At least for me, a similar brute force computation on lengths shows $\theta(D_{\emptyset,J})=D_{\emptyset,J}$. But as soon as $I\neq\emptyset$, the statement is false, which I think is essentially the issue you're pointing out? So I think we're in agreement.